# Syncing iOS Dependencies - across multiple managers/repositories

Tags: ios, dependency-management

I'm the maintainer of [FeathersSwift](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-swift), the iOS client-side SDK for the venerable [FeathersJS](https://feathersjs.com/). In addition to FeathersSwift, I also maintain [FeathersSwiftSocketIO](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-swift-socketio) and [FeathersSwiftRest](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-swift-rest) which are transport providers that plug into the main networking library. Over the course of my work on these libraries I've run into several issues, primarily when it comes to syncing dependencies across a) multiple dependency managers (CocoaPods, Carthage, Swift Package Manager) and b) across multiple repositories.

A quick aside, the decision to split the main networking library (FeathersSwift) and its transport providers into separate repositories was made for two reasons:

- Github visibility.
- Carthage and Swift PM do not have an analougous feature to CocoaPods' `pod FeathersSwift/SocketIO` where you can install subspecs. If kept in the same repository, Carthage/Swift PM users would be forced to download additional dependencies, adding to build times and overall project size. For that reason, the repositories remain separate, to be un-opinionated as possible.

That however, introduces complications. For example, all three libraries depend on ReactiveSwift. How do I ensure that when someone `pod install`s both FeathersSwift and FeathersSwiftRest, that the version of ReactiveSwift that each framework depends on are the same?

Furthermore, there's the issue of locking dependencies between different dependency managers. Each one uses a different format so I'd assume you'd have to write a tool or define a DSL that then gets transpiled into each respective format.

Even more complicated, how do you go about ensuring that multiple repos across multiple dependency managers are all synced? It sounds like you'd have to a) write the tool mentioned above the syncs between dependency managers and then b) a tool that consumes the output of the first tool and syncs the repositories with a manifest file of some kind (in combo with some other repository that's only used for keeping dependencies in sync, sort of like a private CocoaPods spec repository).

Another solution I've toyed with is the iOS monorepo (detailed [here](https://eng.uber.com/ios-monorepo/)). It would necessitate using something like [Buck](https://buckbuild.com/) to build all the separate embedded repositories and there'd be work to translate Buck into things like podspecs and Carthage files. Additionally it would lose visibility in the form of multiple Github repositories but there would still be multiple CocoaPod pages so not a huge loss.

Has anyone run into this issue when writing/maintaining multiple open-source libraries that are co-dependent?